# Java: How to remember where saved file is

Tags: java

In usual programs, you install the program in a directory. I want to do the same thing in mine, but I do not know how to make the program remember where the user chose to save the folder which all the files will be put.

I have this method that takes the directory:

```
public static String hämtaFrånText() {
    String rawURL = "";
    String aktuellMapp = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(aktuellMapp);
    int resultat = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (resultat != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingen fil valdes. Skapandet av en ny sker.");
    } else {
        rawURL = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    }

    return rawURL;
}
```

But how do I save it, so the next time the program opens it knows where the files are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user save the runnable jar-file in a specific folder, you can do:

```
return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().
getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

In order to get the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a preference file (e.g. /%APP_DATA%/.yourapplication/prefs)
and write the URL into it. On startup you could check if that file exists, and if it does read that url.

If you need to save more stuff, you could take a look at the [apache commons configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) libraries - you could, for example, use an XML configuration to save your path.